# How do I align mapsto arrows in latex

Tags: align, amsmath, arrows

I am trying to align the mapsto arrows for a function, but latex just seems to align the arrows and the mess up the space for the numbers or aligns the numbers and but not the arrows. Heres the code:

```
\begin{align*}
\sigma= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      \sqrt[8]{2} \longmapsto \zeta\sqrt[8]{2}
      \\
      i \longmapsto i
      \end{array} 
\right. 
&&
 \tau= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      \sqrt[8]{2} &\longmapsto&\sqrt[8]{2}
      \\
      {i} &\longmapsto& -i
      \end{array}
\right.    
\end{align*}
```

[image]

What I want is the arrows aligned but numbers to stay in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aligned` (not `cases` that's not the right tool). Or `array` if you don't like the output of `aligned` (but it's the best, in my opinion).

In any case, don't use `align*` for single row displays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Right and left alignment
\begin{equation*}
\sigma= 
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    \sqrt[8]{2} & \longmapsto \zeta\sqrt[8]{2} \\
    i           & \longmapsto i
  \end{aligned}
  \right. 
\qquad
\tau=
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    \sqrt[8]{2} & \longmapsto \sqrt[8]{2} \\
      i         & \longmapsto -i
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

Center alignment
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sigma= 
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ c c c }
    \sqrt[8]{2} & {} \longmapsto {} & \zeta\sqrt[8]{2} \\
    i           & {} \longmapsto {} & i
  \end{array}
  \right.
\qquad
\tau=
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ c c c }
    \sqrt[8]{2} & {} \longmapsto {} & \sqrt[8]{2} \\
      i         & {} \longmapsto {} & -i
  \end{array}
  \right.    
\end{equation*}

Left alignment
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sigma= 
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ l c l }
    \sqrt[8]{2} & {} \longmapsto {} & \zeta\sqrt[8]{2} \\
    i           & {} \longmapsto {} & i
  \end{array}
  \right.
\qquad
\tau=
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ l c l }
    \sqrt[8]{2} & {} \longmapsto {} & \sqrt[8]{2} \\
      i         & {} \longmapsto {} & -i
  \end{array}
  \right.    
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the same with `\mapsto` instead of `\longmapsto`.

[image]

Why? Because I feel that `\longmapsto` is not really good, too wide.

Comment: Wow appreciate it, thank you as well. I feel bad that unfortunately I cannot upvote or accept both answers, but thank you for providing a wide variety of formats. I think I like the center alignment the best. Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

By use of the `cases` environment defined in `amsmath` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\sigma = \begin{cases}
    \sqrt[8]{2} & \longmapsto \zeta\sqrt[8]{2}  \\
            i   & \longmapsto i
        \end{cases}
&&
\tau = \begin{cases}
      \sqrt[8]{2} & \longmapsto \sqrt[8]{2}     \\
            i     & \longmapsto -i
       \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much I have been looking around everywhere but I couldn't find a solution so I thought I would post it on here. I cannot upvote unfortunately since I am a new user but thank you! :)

Comment: @GiantSalamander, but you can accept answer ;-). But wait a while  with that. In the meantime you can get a better answer ...